# How to show image into picture box from database?

Tags: c#

I have use following code.

```
foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt.Rows)
{
   picbyte = (byte[])dr1["AssociateImageData"];
   Stream stream = new MemoryStream(picbyte);
   pictureBox1.Image =Image.FromStream(stream,true,true);
}
```

Comment: i have an error "Parameter Not Valid"

Comment: where you get this error at ? Have you tried to debug ?

Comment: why are you passing in 'true,true' to the method and not just the byte[]? I don't think this overload exists.

Comment: but i its not working when i remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
var ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "AssociateImageData");
int count = ds.Tables["AssociateImageData"].Rows.Count;

if (count > 0)
{ 
    var picbyte = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["AssociateImageData"].Rows[count - 1]["AssociateImageData"]);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(picbyte);
    pictureBox1.Image= Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Comment: @pramodnarke:- Did you try to change: `pictureBox1.Image =Image.FromStream(stream);`

Comment: sir i have to load image into picturebox itself. and while debugging Image property is null in pictureBox1.Image=Image.FromStream(stream);

Comment: @pramodnarke:- Check this: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Images-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: @pramodnarke:- Also refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555127/image-file-from-sql-data-table-to-aspimage-control

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me:

```
private void viewSnapShotButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myCconnectionSstring"];

    string queryString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyQueryString"];
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        byte[] image = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();
        MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(image);
        exceptionPictureBox.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(ms1);  //this is how it should be.  I was using Image.FromStream and was getting error.
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

Comment: which data type is to be used for store image in sql server....can i use image or varbinary(max) for same

Comment: `Image` is deprecated, so use `Varbinary`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt.Rows)
{
   picbyte = (byte[])dr1["AssociateImageData"];
   MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(picbyte);
   pictureBox1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream (ms1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the cleanest solution, where the memory is actually cleaned properly.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var comm = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])comm.ExecuteScalar()))
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Could also be done like this if you want to specify the column or use other columns within the row.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var comm = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn)
    {
        using (var reader = new comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])reader["Column"]))
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```